# Issue when customizing select_sequence in sequence library

Tags: uvm

Please help to understand one issue that I am facing when trying to customize the “select_sequence” of the sequence_library.
So I need to customize the “select_sequence” and make my sequences to run in exact order, which is written in external file.
For that reason I am stepping on the container of all registered sequence types: sequences[$]. And doing dynamic casting. If casting matches with my needed sequence I return number from the select_sequence function i.e. making the library to run the sequence.

This is the part from my code:

```
class cfgSeqncLib extends uvm_sequence_library #(seqItem_cfg);
    `uvm_object_utils(cfgSeqncLib)
    `uvm_sequence_library_utils(cfgSeqncLib)

    rstSeqnc resetSequence;

  function int unsigned select_sequence(int unsigned max);
        static int unsigned counter;
        select_sequence = counter;
        counter++; 
        if (counter > max)
            counter = 0;

        foreach (sequences[i])
        begin
                if ($cast(resetSequence, sequences[i]) )
                $display("%t: <><><>><>< ResetSeq: Casting IS Successfull", $time);
            else
                $display("%t: >>>>>>>>ResetSeq: Casting is NOT Successfull", $time);
        end // foreach
  endfunction
endclass
```

And I have added the reset sequence in the library using :  `uvm_add_to_seq_lib(rstSeqnc, cfgSeqncLib) command.

The thing is that the $case never return 1 i.e. during simulation it always print
        \  >>>>>>>>ResetSeq: Casting is NOT Successfull

Even though I can see that reset sequence is being run by the sequence_lib, but never casting returns true.
Can you please explain why?

If using the UVM code, I change the `select_sequence` function to following, than casting works:

```
function int unsigned select_sequence(int unsigned max);
        static int unsigned counter;
        uvm_object_wrapper wrap;
          uvm_object obj;
           select_sequence = counter;
        counter++;
        if (counter > max)
            counter = 0;

     foreach (sequences[i])
        begin
            wrap = sequences[i];
              obj = factory.create_object_by_type(wrap,get_full_name(),
           $sformatf("%s:%0d",wrap.get_type_name(),sequences_executed+1));

            if ($cast(resetSequence, obj) )
                $display("%t: !!!!!!! ResetSeq: Casting IS Successfull", $time);
            else
                $display("%t: >>>>>>>>ResetSeq: Casting is NOT Successfull", $time);

        end // foreach

    endfunction
```

During Simulaiton I am getting:

```
  !!!!!!! ResetSeq: Casting IS Successfull
```

I cannot understand why  casting in the the first version of select_sequence does not work but in second case it works. Can someone explain this to me please.

Answer (score 0):

using the macro `uvm_add_to_seq_lib` to add the sequence into the library  [`uvm_add_to_seq_lib(rstSeqnc, cfgSeqncLib) ] gives us the feeling that its adding an instance of the sequence into an array present in the sequence library and this instance can be used later in the sequence library.

But that is not the case and like the commonly used style within the  uvm, the macro is adding a object of the type `uvm_object_registry`. This object is created (statically) once per class within the `uvm_object_utils` macros [ uvm_object_registry#(T,`"S`") type_id; ].

This mechanism is used within the factory classes/mechanism to create and use a lightweight wrapper(uvm_object_registry) of the object. This ensures that uvm framework is not creating the complete class till its actually needed. The instance of the class is only created at the time of calling the type_id::create function ( or other factory create functions).

So `$cast(resetSequence, sequences[i])` in case 1 is really trying to cast the object_wrapper for the type resetSequence [uvm_object_registry#(resetSequence,"resetSequence") ] into  resetSequence which fails .

```
resetSequence != uvm_object_registry#(resetSequence,"resetSequence")
```

Examining the macro itself we can see its not adding an instance of TYPE ( sequence) instead is calling get_type function which returns an object wrapper.

```
`define uvm_add_to_seq_lib(TYPE,LIBTYPE) \
       static bit add_``TYPE``_to_seq_lib_``LIBTYPE =\
          LIBTYPE::m_add_typewide_sequence(TYPE::get_type());
```

Also examining the code ( case 2 )  below we can see that its using the factory mechanism to create the instance of the class. This ensures that any type override in the environment will work and the sequence library will then use the new sequence over the registered one in the sequence library. In example 1 such a case is not possible as its attempting to directly use the instance of the class [ even if the code was fixed ] . So case 2 has advantages.

```
 wrap = sequences[i];
              obj = factory.create_object_by_type(wrap,get_full_name(),
           $sformatf("%s:%0d",wrap.get_type_name(),sequences_executed+1));

            if ($cast(resetSequence, obj) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now it is clear for me!